# Why does Dask change the contents of csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask

**Conclusion**

It worked fine to add parameter to read_csv.
...But the double quotation is still gone.

The page which became helpful
https://www.kaggle.com/szelee/how-to-import-a-csv-file-of-55-million-rows#369081

---

I read CSV file by Dask and without doing anything write CSV file by dask.
But Dask changes the contents of the csv file.

```py
import os
import dask.dataframe as dd

user_name = os.environ['USERPROFILE'].replace('\\', '/')
dir = user_name + '/Desktop/'

types_dict = {
  'Region': 'object', 
  'Product': 'object',
  'Date': 'object',
  'Sales': 'object'
}
#I changed to the following code. df = dd.read_csv(dir + 'Sales_Data_1.csv')
df = dd.read_csv(dir + 'Sales_Data_1.csv', dtype=types_dict)

# In case of no dtype parameter on read_csv()
# print(df.dtypes)
# Region      object
# Product     object
# Date        object
# Sales      float64
# dtype: object

# Error Occurs
# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Sales_Data_1.csv\\1.part'
#df.to_csv(dir + 'Sales_Data_1.csv')

df.compute().to_csv(dir + 'Sales_Data_1_dask.csv', index=False, quotechar = '"', doublequote = True)
```

I downloaded the CSV file from this site.
https://www.masterdataanalysis.com/ms-excel/analyzing-50-million-records-excel/

**Difference Sales_Data_1.csv and Sales_Data_1_dask.csv**
[diff by Winmerge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMsWw.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Sales_Data_1.csv\\1.part'
#df.to_csv(dir + 'Sales_Data_1.csv')

df.compute().to_csv(dir + 'Sales_Data_1_dask.csv', index=False, quotechar = '"', doublequote = True)
```

Dask dataframe doesn't write a single file (this is hard to do in parallel).  Instead you provide it with a directory and it writes many files to that directory.  I encourage you to read the documentation string for that function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will read the documentation firmly.